# ListView Column Size to Change with Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` where some columns contains `TextBox` controls for the user to enter text. However, if the entered text is too long it will be limited by the current width of the column. Is there a way to automatically resize the width of the column when text is entered overflowing the current size of the column?

[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="List1" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Margin="0 0 5 20" 
            Background="Transparent" 
            Foreground="White" 
            BorderThickness="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Stations}">


    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
                                
        <GridView  AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                                    
            <!-- Location -->
            <GridViewColumn Header="Location">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox>
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Location, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: i recommend you break down you question in a more simple example we can copy and try ourself. right now i feel like your listview style might be interacting with the width

Answer (score 0):

You could try to handle the `TextChanged` event and measure the desired size of the `TextBox`:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
    if (textBox.DesiredSize.Width > col.Width)
        col.Width = textBox.DesiredSize.Width;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100" x:Name="col">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Location, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: That breaks the MVVM pattern (but does of cause work)

Comment: The question isn't labeled MVVM. Also, this is pure view/control related functionality which you can wrap in an attached behaviour if it makes you feel better. It certainly shouldn't be implemented in a view model anyway.